# How to substitute some part of a text based on a dictionary of patterns and substitute values in python using re.sub?

Tags: python, match, regex-group, substitution

I have a list of prefixes that I want to use for text substitution. My program works whenever I am replacing the whole matched text with its corresponding value but not if I want to keep some part of the matched text and replace other parts using grouping:

```
prefixes = {
            r"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#([a-z]+)": r"owl:\1",
            r"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#([a-z]+)": r"rdf:\1",
            r"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#([a-z]+)": r"rdfs:\1",
            r"http://schema.org/": "schema",
            r"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#([a-z]+)": r"xsd:\1",
            r"http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx#([a-z]+)": r"sdmx:\1",
            r"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace": r"xml"
            }
# test = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" # works for this
test = "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#a" # Does not work!

regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, prefixes.keys())))

test = regex.sub(lambda match:prefixes[match.group(0)], test)
```

I want to replace test with "rdfs:a", but it does not work this way. How I should change the code to work in this scenario?

Comment: Okay, you had a pretty complex question, but I have an implementation that does what you want. Also, look at the other answer - it shows how to do replacements by simplifying your requirements on the matching.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Todd. I was more interested to know why my code was not working; assuming that I want to have more complex substitutions. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Did it make sense what I mentioned in my answer about why your code wasn't working?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is *very* complicated. And you actually don't need to use groups and back references to simply replace matching text with another string, as the other answer suggests.

However if there were any reason why the simple approach wouldn't correctly identify the strings you want to replace and the expressions you have in groups are important to the matching, then the below can solve the problem for you.

```
>>> prefixes = {
...     1:  (r"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#([a-z]+)", r"owl:\2"),
...     3:  (r"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#([a-z]+)", r"rdf:\4"),
...     5:  (r"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#([a-z]+)", r"rdfs:\6"),
...     7:  (r"http://schema.org/", "schema"),
...     8:  (r"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#([a-z]+)", r"xsd:\9"),
...     10: (r"http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx#([a-z]+)", r"sdmx:\11"),
...     12: (r"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", r"xml")
...     }
...
>>> test_1 = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
>>> test_2 = "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#a"
>>>
>>> expr = '(' + ')|('.join(p[0] for p in prefixes.values()) + ')'
>>> 
>>> regex = re.compile(expr)
>>> 
>>> regex.findall(test_2)
[('', '', '', '', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#a', 'a', '', '', 
  '', '', '', '')]

>>> regex.sub(lambda m: m.expand(prefixes[m.lastindex][1]), test_2)
'rdfs:a'

>>> regex.sub(lambda m: m.expand(prefixes[m.lastindex][1]), test_1)
'xml'

>>>
```

There!

What you had before wasn't working because the match results were dynamically determined and wouldn't match any of the dictionary keys - which had expressions in them that the target text wouldn't have.

So the problem is how to have a group of expressions associated with a group of replacement strings that have back references in them to the groups in the expression.

What I did was take advantage of the structure of the match object's group list to get the index of the matching expression. If I make every subexpression in the dictionary a group by using parenthesis, then `re.sub()` generates a match object with that many group items in it for every match (see the line with `regex.findall()` - it shows you how the match group list is structured).

The matching subexpression is represented in the match object list as a non-empty string at the position of the parenthesized subexpression.

```
>>> expr = '(' + ')|('.join(p[0] for p in prefixes.values()) + ')'
>>> expr
'(http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#([a-z]+))| 
 (http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#([a-z]+))| 
 (http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#([a-z]+))|
 (http://schema.org/)| 
 (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#([a-z]+))|
 (http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx#([a-z]+))|
 (http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace)'

>>> regex.findall(test_2)
[('', '', '', '', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#a', 'a', '', '', 
  '', '', '', '')]
```

So I modified the `prefixes` data structure to be a dictionary keyed on the position that would be returned by `m.lastindex` - which is the index of the matching parenthesized subexpression.

The back references needed to be adjusted to align with the positions in the match list. For instance `\1` only works to find the first match group in the results.

Another feature of the match object I used was the `m.expand()` method which converts the back references into the groups they reference.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a frame challenge, but "why bother with the groups"?  None of your regular expressions match the end of the line anyways (`$`), so the only thing you lose here is ensuring that everything after `#` starts with a single `a-z` character:

```
import re

prefixes = {
    r"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#": r"owl:",
    r"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#": r"rdf:",
    r"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#": r"rdfs:",
    r"http://schema.org/": "schema",
    r"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#": r"xsd:",
    r"http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx#": r"sdmx:",
    r"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace": r"xml"
}
regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, prefixes.keys())))


test1 = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
test2 = "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#a"

assert regex.sub(lambda match:prefixes[match.group(0)], test1) == "xml"
assert regex.sub(lambda match:prefixes[match.group(0)], test2) == "rdfs:a"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works this way. But I do not understand why I cannot do that as I have in my question. Even if I traverse the dictionary in the for loop, that works with grouping.

Comment: `import re
prefixes = {
            r"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)": r"owl:\1",
            r"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)": r"rdf:\1",
            r"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace": r"xml",
            r"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)": r"xsd:\1",
            r"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)": r"rdfs:\1"
            }

def normalizer(entity):
    for key, value in prefixes.items():
        entity = re.sub(key, value, entity)
    return entity`

Comment: When you do it the way in your question, your `match.group(0)` will contain (for example) the characters `#abc` after "owl" as well, so it will not match any of the options exactly.  You would need to do something weird (e.g. running each regex again or checking prefixes to see what matched, defeating the point).  You can also fix this by using named matches `(?P<name>...)` to simplify, or `(?=` to lookahead match without replacement.